# XPage - fileDownload column order

Tags: xpages

Standard column order of a fileDownload list is `| Type | Size | Name | ... |`
How to change the order to `| Name | Size |  Type | ... |`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the `fileDownload` column order with out of the box properties.

You could

- reorder columns of rendered HTML `<table>` with client side JavaScript or
- create your own download table with a repeat control for example.

But, I am not sure if that's worth the effort...